# How to split and link date field to view (imdb style)

Tags: views, entities, datetime

I have created content type call person (list of persons)
added a date field to content type (birth_date)

1. how to split date to year/month (or should it be two date fields)
2. how to link year to all the people born on that year and month/day to all people born on that day. I know how to create view, but how to make date output as link to it?

Pretty match like imdb does it, not display calendar but text in one line.
birthday: year[link]/ month day[link]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [module](http://dgo.to/date) and code in your theme:

```
/**
 * Override theme_date_display_single().
 *
 * @param $variables
 *   An array of variables to pass to the theme template.
 */
function theme_date_display_single($variables) {
  if($variables['dates']['format'] == "d F Y"){
    // In this case i keep only start date. For keep end date use value2.
    $date = $variables['dates']['value']['formatted_iso'];
    $timezone = $variables['timezone'];
    $attributes = $variables['attributes'];

    $day = format_date(strtotime($date), 'custom', 'd');
    $month = format_date(strtotime($date), 'custom', 'F');
    $year = format_date(strtotime($date), 'custom', 'Y');

    // Wrap the result with the attributes.
    return '<span class="date-display-single"' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>' . '<span class="d">' . $day . '</span>' . '<span class="M">' . $month . '</span>' . '<span class="Y">' . $year . '</span>' . $timezone . '</span>';
  }
}
```